# Python program to calculate the average score and final grade from 3 exams

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

I am making a python 3 program to calculate the average score and final grade (A, B, C, D, F) from 3 exams.   Every time the "Your Grade" output is F.  It Doesn't matter what your exam score is, the grade output is always F. What is wrong?

```
firstexam=0
secondexam=0
thirdexam=0
grade=0
finalgradeABC=0


firstexam = int(input('Enter your first exam: '))
secondexam = int(input('Enter your second exam: '))
thirdexam = int(input('Enter your third exam: '))


allthree =(firstexam + secondexam + thirdexam)


def average(allthree):
    return allthree/3


def yourgrade(avg):
    if 90 <= avg <= 100:
        return 'A'
    elif 80 <= avg <= 89:
        return 'B'
    elif 70 <= avg <= 79:
        return 'C'
    elif 60 <= grade <= 69:
        return 'D'
    else:
        return 'F'


grades = allthree
finalgradeABC = yourgrade(grades)
avg = average(allthree)


print("Average grade is : " + str(avg))
print("You grade : " + str(finalgradeABC))
```

Comment: program works, use 3 scores that do not add upto more then 100 and you get something diffenrent

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is incorrect.  If you enter three scores of 33, you get an 'A'.

The functional problem is that you failed to take the average:

```
allthree =(firstexam + secondexam + thirdexam)
```

Try the correct equation:

```
allthree =(firstexam + secondexam + thirdexam) / 3
```

The structural problem is that you didn't properly account for all cases: you have gaps in your grading scale (i.e. 89.5 is an `F`), and your final clause assumes that anything other than those ranges must be a failing grade.  Instead, try:

```
elif: avg < 60:
    return `F`
else:
    return "bad input or logic error"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want the letter grade for the average grade. If that is the case, then you should call `yourgrade()` on `avg` after you calculate the average, like so:

```
grades = allthree
avg = average(allthree)
finalgradeABC = yourgrade(avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your last few lines to the following - you set up a nice average function, but you forgot to use it before passing a value to the yourgrade() function.

```
avg = average(allthree)
grades = avg
finalgradeABC = yourgrade(grades)
```